# Can Someone Please Tell Me What This Code Does

Tags: python-3.x

```
import imaplib,time

class Mail():
    def __init__(self):
        self.user= 'USERNAME'
        self.password= 'PASSWORD'
        self.M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', '993')
        self.M.login(self.user, self.password)

    def checkMail(self):
        self.M.select()
        self.unRead = self.M.search(None, 'UnSeen')
        return len(self.unRead[1][0].split())



email = Mail()

while 1:
    print ('Sending')
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Theoretically, nothing but print 'Sending'. You initialize `email` as an instance of `MAil` which supposedly logs into an e-mail account over IMAP, but then nothing else happens. You never call `checkMail`.

Also, this question is considered bad form. Why don't you understand the code? Does a particular part confuse you? Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize a `class` called `Mail` that supposedly uses the `imaplib` library to check the unread messages of a gmail account. However, after you assign `email` to an instance of `Mail`, your `while` loop, which is responsible for the action in your code, is comprised of two events; a `print` and a `time.sleep()`.

So your code essentially is a long way of printing `'Sending'` every 2 seconds.

**Running**  *<sup>after commenting out the line `email = Mail()` due to invalid credentials</sup>*

```
bash-3.2$ python foo.py
Sending
Sending
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 21, in <module>
    time.sleep(2)
KeyboardInterrupt
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Ok, so how do I make change the code to check for new emails?